# How to implement Firebase Analytics implementation for AppleTV (tvOS)?

Tags: google-analytics, tvos, firebase-analytics, apple-tv

Currently, we have implemented Google Analytics for AppleTV (tvOS) via Measurement Protocol i.e. using batch end point [Google Analytics - Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide). Now, Google Analytics is [sunsetting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en). Alternative as suggested by Google is Google Analytics for Firebase. But, that implementation is for Mobile Platform.

Does anybody know any workaround that I can use on Firebase Platform in order to report analytics from tvOS using some sort of Firebase API?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is no good news about Firebase Analytics support for tvOS. They don't plan to support it in the near future. Although, there is a community works which make some of Firebase services available for tvOS, you can take a look here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#community-supported-efforts.